# Control published files and folders in app classes folder in wtpwebapps

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp

i am using eclipse **helios 3.6.1** and **WTP 3.2** with **tomcat 7**
and **maven 2** as build tool, **m2eclipse** plugin.

when trying to run project on server from eclipse, i get endless exceptions
this is opposite to running my project from maven tomcat plugin, everything works very fine

so i compared between the extracted war in target folder generated in my project **(workspace/project/target/warFolder)**

and the extracted war in **(wtpwebapps/myapp)**

and here are the contents:

1- **(workspace/project/target/warFolder)** contents:

- com
- messages
- MET-INF
- import.sql
- log4j.properties

2- **(wtpwebapps/myapp)**

- com
- messages
- MET-INF
- import.sql
- log4j.properties
- **src**
- **target**
- **.classpath**
- **.project**
- **file.txt**
- **pom.xml**

why it generates those additional unneeded folders?
when i remove those additional folders and try to run project on server from eclipse it runs fine

so question is how to control eclipse or the m2eclipse or maven or whatever is causing the problem not to generate those folders, and why i get them in first place.

**UPDATE:** POM file plugins

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5</version>
               <configuration>
               <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>

               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
               <configuration>
               <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
               </configuration>


            </plugin>

        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i got this issue solved after removing the following entry from project **deployment assembly**:

**Source:** /   **Deploy Path:**  WEB-INF/classes

but any ideas why i had such entry in first place ?

Comment: It seems like the m2eclipse-wtp configurator did not run, as it's supposed to, well, configure that kind of things for you. When you feel like configuration is incomplete, try to manually force it using right-click on project, Maven > Update Project configuration

Also, when importing projects, use "Import as Maven project", so that configuration step is done automatically.

Comment: i already imported as maven project and updated project configuration, any other ideas why such thing may happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (aka m2eclipse-wtp)?
See https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-wtp/wiki for more details.

Comment: yes, i have it installed, and i guess that i mentioned that in my topic.

Comment: Actually you mentionned you have m2eclipse an WTP installed, nothing said about the glue between the 2, aka m2eclipse-wtp